# Setting up remote access to a single program on a remote personal computer - both Mac & Windows

Tags: windows, macos, remote-access, limited-access

Basically, I'm going to be checking in on one specific program on a few computers, importing new files into that program, and modifying those files a bit. I only need access to one program, but I also need access to the client's database for that program (so for instance, if I'm in iMovie then I need access to the main iMovie library). That access should be constant while the computer's on (like LogMeIn or TeamViewer) and not require the client's approval/presence to initiate a session.

For Macs, it seems like the most straightforward way would be to set up a limited account with heavy parental access restrictions, and just stick their database file on that account. They should be able to access/update it from their admin account. I'd prefer a way that doesn't require creating a new user account, though.

No clues at all what to do on a PC. Everything I've looked at so far seems to be Server 2008 & RemoteApp, which does not seem to me to apply in this situation.

Comment: What Program are you trying to get remote access to on both it may help simplify the question and get you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Any photo management software - might be iPhoto, Aperture, Photos, Picasa, Lightroom, Mylio, or something else I haven't thought of yet. It will vary from person to person.